# pointer increment - weird

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct BLA
{
    int size_;

    int size()const{ return size_; }
}

int x;
BLA b[ 2 ];
BLA * p = &b[ 0 ];

b[ 0 ].size_ = 4;
b[ 1 ].size_ = 6;
```

When I compile this line:

```
x = p->size_ + (p++)->size_;
```

I receive the expected result. But, when I compile this line (without the previous one):

```
x = p->size() + (p++)->size();
```

Then I get different result. The 'p' is not incremented at the same time as in the previous line. Can someone explain this, please? Tried on VS 2008 and VS 2010.

Comment: Would you post the result in the first and the second case, too?

Comment: It's UB. Something very like tricky question about "what is result of ++i++?"

Comment: @Lyubomir, first case 8, seconds case 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour to seperately read and modify a variable without an intervening sequence point. You've seen a good example of the consequences of that.

Answer (score 1):

Upon my compilation of your code, x is 8 in both of my cases. Both separately used, and combined used. I'd like to note that using p++ is considered undefined behavior, and the line in which it warns me is that line.

However, the compiler warns me that `warning: operation on 'p' may be undefined`.

Edit: I'd like to note proper pointer arithmetic would be: `x = p->size_ + (p+1)->size_;` in this situation.